Schema is not loading using Hot Chocolate GraphQL
I am trying to query my database using Hot Chocolate GraphQL but my schema fails to load and I cant seem to figure out why.
Here are the following relevent files
Program.cs
using StockMarketReport.Api.Extensions;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add configuration for connecting to SQL Server
builder.Services.SetUpApiServices(builder.Configuration, builder.Environment);

var app = builder.Build();

await app.ApplyApiServices(builder.Environment)
    .RunWithGraphQLCommandsAsync(args);

app.UseRouting();

app.Run();

ApplicationBuilderExtension.cs

public static class ApplicationBuilderExtensions
{
    internal static WebApplication ApplyApiServices(this WebApplication app, IHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app
            .UseStatusCodePages()

            .UseRouting();

        app.MapGraphQL().WithOptions(new GraphQLServerOptions
        {
            EnableSchemaRequests = true,
            Tool = {
                            Enable = env.IsDevelopment()
                        }
        });


        return app;
    }
}

ServicesExtensions.cs
public static class ServicesExtensions
{

    public static IServiceCollection SetUpApiServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration cfg, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

        services.AddControllers();
        services.ApplyGraphQlServices(cfg, env);

        return services;

    }

    internal static IRequestExecutorBuilder ApplyGraphQlServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration cfg, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        services
        .AddAutoMapper(typeof(GeneralMapping))

        .AddPooledDbContextFactory<StockMarketContext>((_, options) =>
                {
                    options.UseSqlServer(cfg.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString"), conf =>
                    {
                        conf.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery);
                        conf.CommandTimeout(100);
                    });
                })
                .AddScoped(p => p.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<StockMarketContext>>().CreateDbContext());

        return services
        .AddGraphQLServer()
        .AddQueryType<Query>()
        .RegisterService<IMapper>()
        .RegisterDbContext<StockMarketContext>(DbContextKind.Pooled)
        .AddTypes()
        .AddFiltering()
        .AddSorting()
        .AddProjections();
    }
}

query.cs
[QueryType]
public class Query
{
        [UsePaging(IncludeTotalCount = true), UseProjection, UseFiltering, UseSorting]
        [GraphQLDescription("The Description of an Entire Industry")]
        public static IQueryable<IndustriesDto> GetIndustries(StockMarketContext ctx, IMapper mapper)
                => ctx.Industries.AsNoTracking().ProjectTo<IndustriesDto>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider);

        [UsePaging(IncludeTotalCount = true), UseProjection, UseFiltering, UseSorting]
        [GraphQLDescription("The Description of an Entire Industry")]
        public static IQueryable<CompanyDto> GetCompany(StockMarketContext ctx, IMapper mapper)
                => ctx.Company.AsNoTracking().ProjectTo<CompanyDto>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider);

        [UsePaging(IncludeTotalCount = true), UseProjection, UseFiltering, UseSorting]
        [GraphQLDescription("The Description of an Entire Industry")]
        public static IQueryable<CompetitorsDto> GetCompetitors(StockMarketContext ctx, IMapper mapper)
                => ctx.Competitors.AsNoTracking().ProjectTo<CompetitorsDto>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider);


        [UsePaging(IncludeTotalCount = true), UseProjection, UseFiltering, UseSorting]
        [GraphQLDescription("The Description of an Entire Industry")]
        public static IQueryable<MarketTechnicalsDto> GetMarketTechnicals(StockMarketContext ctx, IMapper mapper)
                => ctx.MarketTechnicals.AsNoTracking().ProjectTo<MarketTechnicalsDto>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider);

        [UsePaging(IncludeTotalCount = true), UseProjection, UseFiltering, UseSorting]
        [GraphQLDescription("The Description of an Entire Industry")]
        public static IQueryable<StockGraphDto> GetStockGraph(StockMarketContext ctx, IMapper mapper)
                => ctx.StockGraph.AsNoTracking().ProjectTo<StockGraphDto>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider);

}

If you need to see something else to further help explain my problem then please let me know. Below is the error I get when I run banancakepop
"We were not able to fetch the Schema. Please make sure that you're connected to the internet, using a correct endpoint, the server isn't down and you're not facing any CORS issues. Click on Details to find out more.
"
I am trying to query my Database using a third party library Hot Chocolate with .Net but the schema wont load that I need to query my database. As a result I get the following error:
"We were not able to fetch the Schema. Please make sure that you're connected to the internet, using a correct endpoint, the server isn't down and you're not facing any CORS issues. Click on Details to find out more.
"
